# Controller-routes not properly working in Laravel when deploying

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on an application, and I just started pushing it to my staging server to test it out in in a live environment and ran into an odd problem.

So I have a route set up like this:

```
// AJAX routes
Route::controller('io', 'IoController');
```

And in the IoController I have methods set up:

```
public function getSomeData() {}
public function postSomeData() {}
```

When I run `php artisan routes` on my dev environment (localhost):

```
GET /io/some-data
POST /io/some-data
GET /io/{_missing}
```

But on my staging server I just get:

```
GET /io/{_missing}
```

Of course, checking the route `app.com/io/some-data` just throws an `'Controller method not found'` exeption.

Anyone who have ran into similar problems and resolved them? I really have no idea why this is happening, and where to start looking.

Comment: it is very important to have the case of your controller name to be exactly the same case when they are defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was an issue when upgrading Laravel.

Prior to 4.1 named groups didn't have to include the group name in the URL, but after the update a named resource-group expected the group name to be in the url.

Somehow I managed to have a diff in versions (stupid of me using the dev-branch in composer.json) on the staging and dev-environments.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller actions has to be mapped properly to your route paths.
That error message is telling you just that - there is no method connected to you paths. By default, Laravel is using resourceful routes and your path are mapped to list of actions which are named like this:

- index with http GET method
- create with http GET method
- store with http POST method
- show with http GET method
- edit with http GET method
- update with http PUT method
- delete with http DESTROY method

You can create your custom methods but you have to be explicit about that and tell to routes where to find those actions, like this:

```
Route::get("path","SomeController@SomeMethodName");
```

In most cases, I would recommend using excellent Jeffrey Ways [generators package](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)

Which will with one command, generate whole resource for you; including migrations, model, controllers, actions...

And you can use that resource like this:

```
  Route::resource("path","SomeController");
```